# How to identify date is in seconds or minutes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, integer, type-conversion

I have a integer number say Int64 i. the data in this variable is both in minute format and seconds format. Ho can identify the integer number is in munutes or in seconds

suppose,

```
Int64 i = 0;
```

now values may be..(For date 2016-02-18 00:00:00:000)

```
i = 1140220800; //(value is in seconds)
//or 
i = 19003680; //(value is in minutes i.e. 1140220800/60)
```

No how to identify data is in minutes or seconds ?

Comment: There is no minute or second format since you have an integer. Why do you think `19003680` _can't_ be as second for example?

Comment: ignore it..it just output from DATEADD(SS,1140220800,'1980') from sql server, it will give me full date.

Comment: Why you want to use two units (Second and minutes) for above value ?

Comment: for ex. convert the date ' 2016-02-18' into integer with seconds or minutes like   datediff(ss,'1980','2016-02-18') and datediff(mi,'1980','2016-02-18')

Comment: my input values are from different sources and in different formats (like one in minute and other in seconds)

Comment: Quick quiz - what output should be produced for the input 75288462? If *you* can't answer, and *we* can't answer, why do you expect that a *computer* can work it out?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I am finding any way/logic to differentiate 'seconds' and 'minutes'. And we are sure that date is in either in min or secs.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just **assume** that if the number if smaller than some threshold value which makes sense in your context then it's minutes, else it's seconds. For example:

```
int number = 19003680;
if(number < 42076800) // 2050-01-01 in minutes, 1971-03-05 in seconds.
{
    // minutes
}
else
{
    // seconds
}
```

However, this question goes against the principles of good programming - one variable should only have one meaning. If a variable can represent both seconds and minutes, there's a problem in the design of your data.

**EDIT:**
If you can't reasonably fence your data to where seconds and minutes don't overlap - that is, if you can have both large dates represented in seconds, and small dates represented in minutes, then sadly it's impossible to differentiate between the two.

Comment: I can't restrict the input date like this.. some dates are '2300-01-01' .Now in this case how can I handle it ?

Comment: I agree that second and minute date should be in different variables. but I need some solution to for a limited time span so that I can avoid change in design.